# How to slide down an old toaster of AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angular-toastr

I made two `toasters` using **`AngularJS Toaster`**.

> The No.1 toaster's option is "limit : 10, position-class : toast-top-center".
>   The No.2 toaster's option is "limit : 1, position-class : toast-top-center".

When I use two toasters together, they overlaps.
I want to **slide down the old one when the new taster appears.**

One solution is to use only **No.1** toaster more than once, however I want to use **No.1** and **No.2** toasters together.

Any options of the toaster or any ideas?

Comment: What's the reasoning for using two toasters?  The exact behaviour that you want is achievable with a single toaster instance.

Comment: The reasoning for using two toasters is to permit multi toasters for only No.1 toaster. For example, when the code is written to use four toasters(No.1, No.1, No.2, No.2) together, I want to show three toasters No.1, No.1, No.2. I want to limit No.2 toaster's number to appear.